# CakePHP HTML Helper adding prefix URL

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to append CDN url to all image resources across the site.

current code looks like this `$this->Html->image('img.png')`. I found that there's an option to append baseURL `['fullBase' => true]`, but I couldn't find an option to append custom URL that would route to desired CDN. Is there a way to create a custom setting that would point to CDN url such as `['CDN_URL_1' => true]` or any other clean way to achieve this?

The other approach I can think about is appending path like so `$this->Html->image($customURL.'img.png')`, but this might not be the correct approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the base URL for those items in your config file (`./Config/bootstrap.php`).

See [Configuration](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html).

> **App.imageBaseUrl**
>
> Web path to the public images directory under webroot. If you are
>   using a CDN you should set this value to the CDN’s location.
>
> **App.cssBaseUrl**
>
> Web path to the public css directory under webroot. If you are using a
>   CDN you should set this value to the CDN’s location.
>
> **App.jsBaseUrl**
>
> Web path to the public js directory under webroot. If you are using a
>   CDN you should set this value to the CDN’s location.

```
...
Configure::write('App.imageBaseUrl', 'http://yourcdn.com/img/');
Configure::write('App.jsBaseUrl', 'http://yourcdn.com/js/');
Configure::write('App.cssBaseUrl', 'http://yourcdn.com/css/');
...
```

Then just use `$this->Html->image('img.png')` normally.

Comment: this is much cleaner compared to what I had in mind, thanks!